# IF statement loop with Range instead of individual values

Tags: excel, vba

First of all thanks for your help.

I've been trying to get a dynamic list that copies values from on excel to another depending on an "IF" condition, which has worked quite fine. But I can only do it for 1 condition instead of a Range of conditions.

In excel I would usually use the COUNTIF function to see if you can find a range of values inside another range, but i am quite new to VBA and I wouldn't know how how to express this in a loop for a Range.

**Example below of what has worked with one condition**:

As you can see I am using "Investor" as my condition, but I need it to be for a range of values.

Thanks for your help!

```
LastRows = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 2 To LastRows

If Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i).Value = "Investor" Then
'Instead of "Investor" I want to do something that take a list of values. Eg : If If Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i).Value = "Range("A1:A"&LastRows) Then

Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & i).Copy
Worksheets("Email Format").Activate

LastRowEmail = Worksheets("Email Format").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Worksheets("Email Format").Range("A" & LastRowEmail).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Application.Match Vs WorksheetFunction.Match

You can use one of the following `Match` solutions.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MultiCriteria1()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsD As Worksheet: Set wsD = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    Dim wsE As Worksheet: Set wsE = wb.Worksheets("Email Format")
    Dim LastRowD As Long: LastRowD = wsD.Cells(wsD.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim CurrentE As Long: CurrentE = wsE.Cells(wsE.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To LastRowD
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(wsD.Range("F" & i).Value, _
          wsD.Range("A1:A" & LastRowD), 0)) Then
            CurrentE = CurrentE + 1
            wsE.Range("A" & CurrentE).Value = wsD.Range("A" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub MultiCriteria2()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsD As Worksheet: Set wsD = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    Dim wsE As Worksheet: Set wsE = wb.Worksheets("Email Format")
    Dim LastRowD As Long: LastRowD = wsD.Cells(wsD.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim CurrentE As Long: CurrentE = wsE.Cells(wsE.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim CurrVal As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To LastRowD
        On Error Resume Next
        CurrVal = WorksheetFunction.Match(wsD.Range("F" & i).Value, _
          wsD.Range("A1:A" & LastRowD), 0)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            CurrentE = CurrentE + 1
            wsE.Range("A" & CurrentE).Value = wsD.Range("A" & i).Value
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: As the value of the `Match` is being discarded anyway (we only care about it not being an error), would `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` be a safer method?

Comment: @Chronocidal: `CountIf` is less efficient, since it loops (counts) through the whole range, while `Match` just loops until a match is found. I didn't encounter any problems with `Match` used either way, did you?

Comment: @vBasic2008 Thanks! I will try it tomorrow but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example but should steer you in right direction.

```
Dim rngYourRange as Range
Set rngYourRange = Range("A1:C10")
Dim rngEachRange as Range

For each rngEachRange in rngYourRange 'or rngYourRange.Rows or rngYourRange.Columns
    if rngEachRange.value = 1 then 'or whatever
    'do what you need
    end if
next rngEachRange
```

Comment: I see, then I can ad d a dynamic value to rngEachRange like i=2 and then allow it to compare to each cell of the defined range "rngYourRange".